# How to prove that $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-numbers, rational-numbers

How to proof that $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$, where $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{Q}^{\prime}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{\prime}$ are the limit points of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Hint: for any $r\in\Bbb R$, take decimal expansion of $r$ and cut it at various points.

Comment: @Wojowu, Could you elaborate more please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Show that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ by showing that any basic open set contains a rational point. The basic open sets are sets of the form:
$\{x-\epsilon<y<x+\epsilon\}$ as $\epsilon$ and $x$ range over all real numbers. Note that this is the same as saying that a basic open set is an interval of the form $(a,b)$ for $a<b \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Say you already proved that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ what do you do then?

Comment: Depends which definition of dense you are using. One definition of $A$ being dense in $B$ is that the closure of $A$ in $B$ denoted $\overline A$ is all of $B$. I guess you are using the other common definition that every open set in $B$ intersects $A$. It is not too hard to prove they are equivalent. Try assuming the second and the negation of the first and arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: I have already proved that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ by showing that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x>y$, $\exists q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $y<q<x$

Comment: not sure what to do next

Comment: Yes so prove the equivalence of the two definitions I mentioned in my other comment and you are done. Proving the equivalence is just a matter of unpacking definitions.

Comment: The equivalence in fact holds for any general topological space. That might make things easier to prove.

Comment: Do you say some thing like this: Since $y<q<x$ then $x,y$ are limit points of $\mathbb{Q}$ i.e. $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}^{\prime}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}=\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$

Comment: Let x be real.  Let $\epsilon > 0$. $N_{\epsilon}(x) = (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$.  If there are any rationals in that intervals then that proves x is a limit point because every neighborhood contains a point of Q.